# How to show <sj:select> in jQuery dialog

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, jquery-ui-dialog, struts2-jquery

I have a scenario where upon clicking a button, I open a jQuery dialog which renders a JSP (Struts) form through Ajax call as shown below.

This form has a `<sj:select>` tag which receives entries from a object `List`. The list is populating correctly but it does not show up on the dialog instead it shows on the parent JSP page from where I open the dialog.

Here's my parent JSP code:

```xml
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

$("#mydialogpopup").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : "popupAjax.action",
        success : function(response) { 
            $("#form_add").html(response);
         $("#form_add").dialog('open');
        }
 });
 });
     $("#form_add").dialog({autoOpen: false, 
         modal: true,
         width: 450,
        height: 280
     });

</script>


<a href="#" id="mydialogpopup" class="isw-plus"></a>

<div class="newdialog" id="form_add" style="display: block;" title="My Dialog"></div>
```

Here's the code of my `popup.jsp` page which is rendered as a successful result of Ajax call:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib  uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>      
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<sj:head/>
 <link href="jsp/css/stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
  
  <s:form id="userForm" action="" method="post" >
    
  <s:url id="remoteurl" action="listUser"/>                         
                            <sj:select
                            href="%{remoteurl}"
                            id="echo3"
                            cssStyle="width: 100%;"
                            name="echo" 
                            list="userList" 
                            listKey="id" 
                            listValue="name"
                            autocomplete="true"
                            emptyOption="true"
                            headerKey="-1" 
                            loadMinimumCount="2"
                            headerValue="Please Select a User" />
    
    <sj:submit targets="result" id="savedialog" value="Save" validate="true"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="button" id="closedialog" value="Cancel"/>
    
    </s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't load jQuery library twice on the same page. First time you load it with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

the second time you load it with

```
<sj:head/>
```

Also you should not use these tags on the rendered page

```
<html>
<head>
<sj:head/>
 <link href="jsp/css/stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

The page that you render is not a full html page, but a part of it, and you should render only tags that are suitable for the parent tag's body. Because you render to the `div` tag it's position is defined by the CSS style and could be floating out of the dialog. Make sure you use `position: relative` style.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I corrected the code and it still did not work. After doing some more research , I found that it is a defect in struts..Here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1022